# Hazelcast 3.11 client connection retry config problem -

Tags: distributed-computing, hazelcast

I am trying to use connection retry as explained here:

[https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.11/manual/html-single/index.html#configuring-client-connection-retry](http://%20https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.11/manual/html-single/index.html#configuring-client-connection-retry)

Setting  the config as below

```
 <connection-strategy async-start="true" reconnect-mode="ASYNC">
        <connection-retry enabled="true">
            <initial-backoff-millis>2000</initial-backoff-millis>
            <max-backoff-millis>60000</max-backoff-millis>
            <multiplier>3</multiplier>
            <fail-on-max-backoff>false</fail-on-max-backoff>
            <jitter>0.5</jitter>
        </connection-retry>
    </connection-strategy>
```

Gives the following error:

```
Factory method 'client' threw exception; nested exception is com.hazelcast.config.InvalidConfigurationException: cvc-complex-type.2.1: Element 'connection-strategy' must have no character or element information item [children], because the type's content type is empty.
```

https://hazelcast.com/schema/client-config/hazelcast-client-config-3.11.xsd

The child element seems to be missing?

```
<xs:complexType name="connection-strategy">
<xs:attribute name="async-start" type="xs:boolean" default="false" use="optional"/>
<xs:attribute name="reconnect-mode" type="reconnect-mode" default="ON" use="optional"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

How can I use connection-retry feature?

Thanks

Regards

Answer (score 0):

This is  due to a silly classpath problem in my application. There is no error. Sorry for the inconvenience